# How to list get a list of all TestNG test methods

Tags: testng

I've got a test-suite, where I'd like to get a full list of all TestNG test-methods (fully qualified).

Example output I need:

```
com.package.SomeTest.testSomething
com.package.OtherTest.testOtherThing
```

How can I get this list of methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach to get a full list of all test-methods is to execute the test suite with a `org.testng.ISuiteListener`. This listener gets the fully populated `ISuite` which provides a `List` of all test-methods which will be executed.

---

The `ISuiteListener` provides an `onStart` method, which is called before any of the test-methods are executed. This allows us to grab list of all test-methods that will be executed and write them to a file.

Here the `ISuiteListener` I've used:

```
package helper;

import org.testng.ISuite;
import org.testng.ISuiteListener;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class LogSuiteListener implements ISuiteListener {
    @Override
    public void onStart(ISuite suite) {
        try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("/tmp/test-list.txt"))) {
                suite.getAllMethods().stream()
                .map(m -> m.getTestClass().getName() + "." + m.getMethodName())
                .forEach(out::println);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("FAILED TO WRITE TO FILE!");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish(ISuite suite) {}
}
```

I'm using Lambdas in this example, but the `onStart` method can also be rewritten with pre-Java8 feature as follows:

```
for (ITestNGMethod m : suite.getAllMethods()) {
    out.println(m.getTestClass.getName() + "." + m.getMethodName());
}
```

---

To add the listener to the TestNG-Suite just add the following XML-Snipped to your testng.xml suite definition:

```
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="helper.LogSuiteListener"/>
</listeners>
```

---

As a side note: If you only need the list of tests, which will be executed. You only need to start the TestNG-runner with the listener defined, and after the output file has been written the actual execution of the tests can be canceled.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I've developed a [library](https://github.com/AutomatedOwl/testng-disabled-tests) which does it but particularity for disabled tests. With just a few modifications you can set it to output all of the tests.

Just go to the following code:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    if (matcher.group().contains("enabled = false") | matcher.group().contains("enabled=false")) {
        Matcher disabledTestMatcher = DISABLED_TEST_REGEX_EXPRESSION.matcher(matcher.group());
        disabledTestMatcher.find();

        // Add extracted test and remove all its strings but test name.
        extractedTests.add(disabledTestMatcher.group()
                .replace("void", "")
                .replace("{", "")
                .replace("()",""));
    }
```

and remove the entire 'if' clause and output matcher.group().