# How to get a list of all Test Methods belonging to a specific TestNG group?

Tags: selenium, testng

How to get a list of all the test methods that are tagged with a specific TestNG group?

Example input:

```
group1
```

Example output I need:

```
com.package.SomeTest.testSomething
com.package.OtherTest.testOtherThing
```

Comment: https://www.guru99.com/introduction-testng-groups.html you might want this

Answer (score 0):

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52943529/3379369

You can use ISuiteListener which provides an onStart method.

```
public void onStart(ISuite suite) {
    try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("/tmp/test-list.txt"))) {
            suite.getAllMethods().stream()
            .map(m -> m.getTestClass().getName() + "." + m.getMethodName())
            .forEach(out::println);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("FAILED TO WRITE TO FILE!");
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: This gets all the test methods irrespective of the group. How do I get only the methods that belong to a specific group?